# What are the advantages of declaring methods in classes instead of functions?

Tags: python, django

1. This is the normal/right way to do in a Django project:

   in models.py

   ```
   class Reservation():

       def cancel_reservation(self):
            # ....

       @classmethod
       def get_client_reservations(cls):
   ```
2. The alternative way that I found in a company codebase:

   in models.py

   ```
   class Reservation():
       # There is no method here except __unicode__
   ```

   and in manage_reservations.py

   ```
   def cancel_reservation(reservation):
       # ...

   def get_client_reservations():
       # ...
   ```

I'd like to have an exshaustive list of the consequences of choosing the first way instead of the second one.

Comment: If your company uses the second one you need to speak to your manager and either convince them that what they're doing is wrong (your words not mine) or learn why you need to use it

Comment: I don't feel like the first way is definitively better. For example, get_client_reservations() might more appropriately be part of a Client class than a Reservation class. Or, if cancel_reservation() needs to have side effects outside of the scope of the Reservation itself, it might be cleaner to have it outside of Reservation rather than passing a bunch of references into Reservation.

Comment: Not specific to this case, but related: [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

Answer (score 3):

It's a coding style. "Object" in OOP is data **and** methods, together. The object has everything you need to hold the data and manipulate it.  There is no "right" answer, more opinion and style.

So you can write:

```
r = Reservation.objects.get(pk=1)
r.get_client_reservation()
```

Rather then:

```
from . import get_client_reservation
get_client_reservation(r)
```

But the truth is that Python modules are a very good solution to keep things together, and it's easier to debug than a complex inheritance chain.

In django the OOP is essential because the framework lets you easily subclass components and customise only what you need, this is hard to do without objects.

If you need a specific form, with specific fields, then you can write it as a simple module with functions. But if you need a generic "Form" that everybody can customise (or a model, authentication backend etc), you need OOP.

So bottom line (IMHO): if Reservation is at the bottom of the pyramid, the end line of data and code, no big difference, more personal preference. If it's in the top and you are going to need ReservationThis and ReservationThat, OOP is better.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a technical answer, but try doing a [git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) on that code, and seeing who wrote the methods, and ask them why they chose to do it like that. In general it's better to keep the methods on the class (for multiple reasons) - for example being able to do dir(r) (where r is a reservation) and seeing all the methods on r. There may be a reason though (that we can't know unless we saw the code)

Answer (score 0):

You shoud put a method inside a class if the it's related with the class, for example if it needs some class variable or if it logically belongs with the class